# Convert Sql to linq with groupby

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, linq, asp.net-core

I have view on which I use this request

```
Select Spendband, SUM(SpendCurrencyJob), SUM(SpendDocumentCount)
From analysis.vwJobSupplierMetrics
Where JobId = '500E0DD1-E3D3-4887-95EF-01D3C9EA8FD0'
Group by SpendBand
```

And it's running sucessfully

and get me this data

[image]

How I need to write it using linq to get same data?

I tried like this

```
    var data = await _dbContext.VwJobSupplierMetrics.Where(x => x.JobId == jobId)
            .GroupBy(x => x.SpendBand)
            .Select(x => new HumpChartDto() {SpendBand = x.SpendBand}).ToListAsync();
```

But on `new HumpChartDto() {SpendBand = x.SpendBand}` I got `Cannot resolve symbol 'SpendBand`

How I can solve this?

Comment: I think it should be x.key instead of x.SpeedBound

Comment: okay, but for another 2 fields? @qamar

Comment: Assuming you want to do a sum of each key, here is what you can try x => new HumpChartDto() {SpendBand = x.Key, Total = x.Sum()}

Comment: This may not answer if you are keen on LINQ query, since you are using .NET Core and Entity Framework Core, you can consider applying the [`.FromSqlRaw()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql) by providing the SQL query with the parameter and also create a [Keyless entity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keyless-entity-types?tabs=data-annotations).

Comment: Your SQL query is not correct. Group by should have all columns as in select. Other thing use lindpad to convert your sql to linq.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, after grouping on `SpendBand`, you need to access it via `Key` property. Second, to compute Sum, you can use `Sum` method.

```cs
var data = await _dbContext.VwJobSupplierMetrics.Where(x => x.JobId == jobId)
    .GroupBy(x => x.SpendBand)
    .Select(x => new HumpChartDto() 
    {
        SpendBand = x.Key,
        SumOfSpendCurrencyJob = x.Sum(s => s.SpendCurrencyJob),
        SumOfSpendDocumentCount= x.Sum(s => s.SpendDocumentCount),
    })
    .ToListAsync();
```

Note - change the property name accordingly for name I've used for SumOfSpendCurrencyJob and SumOfSpendDocumentCount as don't know the definition of HumpChartDto class.